# sql exception Can not issue executeUpdate for SELECTs with SELECT query

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm beginner in java field and i'm working on a project books store. I have created a purchase link which is redirected to purchase servlet and in purchase servlet i have my sql query through which i'm fetchin the book details of the selected book but the sql is throwing exception of can not issue executeUpdate for SELECTs.
Thanks for the help in advance
here is my jsp code where i have purchase link

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection con=null;
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:/
/localhost:3306jsp","root","root");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from books where
book_type='Thriller Book'");
out.print("<table width='80%'>");
out.print("<tr><th>ID</th><th>Book Name</th><th>Book Author</th><th>Book
Price</th><th>Book Category</th><th></th></tr>");
while(rs.next())
{
    String str1=rs.getString("id");
    String str2=rs.getString("book_name");
    String str3=rs.getString("book_author");
    String str4=rs.getString("book_price");
    String str5=rs.getString("book_type");
    out.println("<tr><td align='center'>"+str1+"</td><td
    align='center'>"+str2+"</td><td align='center'>"+str3+"</td><td
    align='center'>"+str4+"</td><td align='center'>"+str5+"</td><td
    align='center'><a href=\"./purchase?id="+str1+"\">Purchase</a>
    </td></tr>");
}
out.print("</table>");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my purchase servlet where i have my sql code

```
package purchase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/purchase")
public class Purchase extends HttpServlet 
{

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
response) throws ServletException, IOException 

{   

PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();   
Connection con=null;
try 
    {
    String str1=request.getParameter("id");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
    /jsp","root","root");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select
    book_name,book_author,book_price from books where id=?");
    ps.setString(1,str1);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();
    if(i!=0)
        {
        out.println("Details");
        }
    else if(i==0)

        {
        out.println("<table>");
        out.print("<tr><td>Book Name</td><td>Book Author</td><td>Book
        Price</td><td>Purchase</td></tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        }
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) 
        {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Surely the error points you to the fact that `executeUpdate` isn't really for SELECT statements, try using `executeQuery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a `SELECT`, so you should be calling `executeQuery()`, not `executeUpdate()`:

```
String sql = "SELECT book_name, book_author, book_price FROM books WHERE id=?";
Statement ps = con.createStatement();
ps.setString(1, str1);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String bookName = rs.getString("book_name");
    // etc.
}
```